# Angular 2 Unit Tests: Cannot find name 'describe'

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, jasmine

I'm following [this tutorial from angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#jasmine-101)

As they said, I've created hero.spec.ts file to create unit tests:

```
import { Hero } from './hero';
describe('Hero', () => {
  it('has name', () => {
    let hero: Hero = {id: 1, name: 'Super Cat'};
    expect(hero.name).toEqual('Super Cat');
  });
  it('has id', () => {
    let hero: Hero = {id: 1, name: 'Super Cat'};
    expect(hero.id).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

Unit Tests work like a charm. The problem is: I see some errors, which are mentioned in tutorial:

> Our editor and the compiler may complain that they don’t know what `it`
> and `expect` are because they lack the typing files that describe
> Jasmine. We can ignore those annoying complaints for now as they are
> harmless.

And they indeed ignored it. Even though those errors are harmless, it doesn't look good in my output console when I receive bunch of them.

Example of what I get:

> Cannot find name 'describe'.
>
> Cannot find name 'it'.
>
> Cannot find name 'expect'.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: You can upvote on Github to fix this bug: https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/1125

Answer (score 431, accepted):

I hope you've installed -

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jasmine
```

Then put following import at the top of the `hero.spec.ts` file -

```
import 'jasmine';
```

It should solve the problem.

Comment: If in Windows Powershell you have to do `npm install --save-dev "@types/jasmine"` (notice the double quotes) or will throw an error

Comment: Depending on the version of Typescript required you may need to  install an earlier version.  e.g For ionic v2.2.1 that I'm currently using that uses typescript v2.0.9, I needed to install `@types/jasmine@2.5.41`. Otherwise you may see [these compilation errors](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/14569).

Comment: You could just import the module for its side effects: `import 'jasmine';`

Comment: What does `import {} from 'jasmine';` actually do? Is it the same as `import 'jasmine'`?

Comment: I actually had similar problem with @types/jest, but it still applies

Comment: IN ANGULAR 6.0.3: I just imported "import {} from jasmine" and it worked again

Comment: It doesn't display 'describe, it, expect' in red error color, when 'import {} from 'jest';' but I am not supposed to put this expression, as it means nothing, as it does nothing (and there is no error on the console), but Webstorm continues displaying 'describe, it, expect' in red error color

Comment: Turns out doing this once in one spec file removed 560 errors being shown in Visual Studio 2017 ... so ... thanks? :)

Comment: @aesede What version of PS do you run? I just executed the command without any quotations marks and it went just well.

Comment: I dropped using Windows 2 years ago, so I can't say what version it was, but is possible the solution came from an update in npm

Comment: just `import 'jasmine';` will result in Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jasmine'.  `import {} from 'jasmine';` is the correct statement

Answer (score 183):

With Typescript@2.0 or later you can install types with:

```
npm install -D @types/jasmine
```

Then import the types automatically using the `types` option in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"types": ["jasmine"],
```

This solution does not require `import {} from 'jasmine';` in each spec file.

Comment: Per TypeScript docs for tsconfig.json (v2.1 at this time), its not necessary to add the `"types": ["jasmine"]` line anymore.  "By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/, ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on."

Comment: @bholben I know, but for some reason `node` and `jasmine` types are not detected. At least it doesn't work for me and I'm using Typescript@2.1.5

Comment: This solution does not work for me :(, sorry. I used it in `ang-app/e2e/tsconfig.json`.  _I tried it in every json level_. Could you please add more details?

Comment: This would not work when using webpack  - in this case the actual library needs to be served - the import {} from 'jasmine' pushes the library through

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to upgrade my global typescript to 3.5.3 (from 2.5)

Comment: @Sergii the tsconfig.json in the src folder

Comment: This solution worked for me. However I had to add it the base `tsconfig.json` file. My project is created with angular/cli so it comes with few different tsconfig files one which is `tsconfig.spec.json` which has `"types": [ "jasmine" ]` already. But seems like it is not read. Instead I had to add that to the base tsconfig file.

Comment: Additionally - if there is a tsconfig.json and others that extend from it - tsconfig.spec.json for tests. Then the types: array in the parent will override the types array in the children. So I deleted the types in the parent and set the test types I wanted in the child e.g. types: ["jasmine"]

Answer (score 28):

```
npm install @types/jasmine
```

As mentioned in some comments the `"types": ["jasmine"]` is not needed anymore, all `@types` packages are automatically included in compilation (since v2.1 I think).

In my opinion the easiest solution is to exclude the test files in your **tsconfig.json** like:

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
]
```

This works for me.

Further information in the official [tsconfig docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

Comment: just a note: new Angular projects have `src/tsconfig.app.json`, `src/tsconfig.spec.json` and `tsconfig.json`. The mentioned "exclude" section is part of the 1st one. `"types": [ "jasmine" ]` part of the 2nd.

Comment: Note that in VS Code you lose the ability to find references in your spec files, as they will not be considered part of the Project.

Comment: @mleu I am facing the same problem. How did you fix this issue? Every time while writing the test case, I have to remove the spec files pattern from the `exclude` block.

Comment: @ShishirAnshuman: I did not find a solution and had to live with this limitation until the project ended.

Comment: @mleu Oh. No issue. In my project as a workaround, I removed the spec file pattern from the tsconfig's `exclude` block. Then I created a new `tsconfig.build.json` file with the spec file pattern added to the `exclude` block. Now, in my `ts-loader` options(in the webpack.config) I am using `tsconfig.build.json`. With these configurations, the modules are being resolved in the test files and while creating the build or starting the server, the test files are excluded.

Comment: Files included using "include" can be filtered using the "exclude" property. However, files included explicitly using the "files" property are always included regardless of "exclude". The "exclude" property defaults to excluding the node_modules, bower_components, jspm_packages and <outDir> directories when not specified.

You should add `"exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts"]` in the `tsconfig.app.json` file, not in the parent.

Answer (score 15):

You need to install typings for jasmine.  Assuming you are on a relatively recent version of typescript 2 you should be able to do:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jasmine
```

Answer (score 13):

With Typescript@2.0 or later you can install types with npm install

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jasmine
```

then import the types automatically using the **typeRoots** option in tsconfig.json.

```
"typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
```

This solution does not require import {} from 'jasmine'; in each spec file.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. It still shows the errors in the spec files

Answer (score 6):

In order for TypeScript Compiler to use all visible Type Definitions during compilation, `types` option should be removed completely from `compilerOptions` field in `tsconfig.json` file.

This problem arises when there exists some `types` entries in `compilerOptions` field, where at the same time `jest` entry is missing.

So in order to fix the problem, `compilerOptions` field in your `tscongfig.json` should either include `jest` in `types` area or get rid of `types` comnpletely:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "types": ["reflect-metadata", "jest"],  //<--  add jest or remove completely
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, I had ``google map types`` in the ``types`` option. 
After removing the option completely, it worked fine.

Comment: Yes. I just had to delete the types thing and works! <3

Answer (score 3):

Solution to this problem is connected with what [@Pace has written](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39023396/1804027) in his answer. However, it doesn't explain everything so, if you don't mind, I'll write it by myself.

**SOLUTION:**

Adding this line:

```
///<reference path="./../../../typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts"/>
```

at the beginning of `hero.spec.ts` file fixes problem. Path leads to `typings` folder (where all typings are stored).

To install typings you need to create `typings.json` file in root of your project with following content:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160807145350"
  }
}
```

And run `typings install` (where `typings` is NPM package).

Comment: this is non-standard way of doing this. default tslint rules will prevent reference paths. use the tsconfig file to point to node_modules

Answer (score 3):

I'm up to the latest as of today and found the best way to resolve this is to do nothing...no `typeRoots` no `types` no `exclude` no `include` all the defaults seem to be working just fine. Actually it didn't work right for me until I removed them all. I had:

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]
```

but that's in the defaults so I removed that.

I had:

```
"types": [
    "node"
]
```

to get past some compiler warning. But now I removed that too.

The warning that shouldn't be is:
`error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterable'.`
from `node_modules\@types\graphql\subscription\subscribe.d.ts`

which is very obnoxious so I did this in tsconfig so that it loads it:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
}
```

since it's in the esnext set. I'm not using it directly so no worries here about compatibility just yet. Hope that doesn't burn me later.

Comment: You don't need to add `"types": ["node"]` in `tsconfig.json` but you should add this type in `tsconfig.app.json` ! You should don't have this warning again I think.
You could keep `"target": "es5"` or `"target": "es6"` now.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the solution was to remove the `typeRoots` in my `tsconfig.json`.

As you can read in the [TypeScript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

> If typeRoots is specified, only packages under typeRoots will be included.

Answer (score 3):

I'll just add Answer for what works for me in "typescript": "3.2.4" I realized that jasmine in node_modules/@types there is a folder for ts3.1 under the jasmine type so here are the steps:-

- Install type jasmine `npm install -D @types/jasmine`
- Add to tsconfig.json jasmine/ts3.1

  `"typeRoots": [
    ...
    "./node_modules/jasmine/ts3.1"
  ],`
- Add Jasmine to the types

  `"types": [
    "jasmine",
    "node"
  ],`

***Note:*** No need for this `import 'jasmine';` anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Only had to do the following to pick up @types in a **Lerna Mono-repo**
where several node_modules exist.

```
npm install -D @types/jasmine
```

Then in each tsconfig.file of each module or app

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types",
  "../../node_modules/@types" <-- I added this line
],
```

Comment: By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/, ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on.

See [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was getting this error when I serve the app, not when testing. I didn't realise I had a different configuration setting in my tsconfig.app.json file.

I previously had this:

```
{
  ...
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

It was including all my `.spec.ts` files when serving the app. I changed the `include property to`exclude` and added a regex to exclude all test files like this:

```
{
  ...
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/__mocks__"
  ]
}
```

Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error in an angular library. Turns out I accidentally included my .spec file in the exports in my public-api.ts. Removing the export fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the import maybe you have a **cycle dependency**, this was in my case the error, using `import {} from 'jasmine';` will fix the errors in the console and make the code compilable but not removes the root of devil (in my case the cycle dependency).

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Angular 6, Typescript 2.7, and I'm using Jest framework to unit test.
I had `@types/jest` installed and added on `typeRoots` inside `tsconfig.json`

But still have the display error below (i.e: on terminal there is no errors)

> cannot find name describe

And adding the import :

```
import {} from 'jest'; // in my case or jasmine if you're using jasmine
```

doesn't technically do anything, so I thought, that there is an import somewhere causing this problem, then I found, that if delete the file

> tsconfig.spec.json

in the `src/` folder, solved the problem for me. As @types is imported before inside the rootTypes.

I recommend you to do same and delete this file, no needed config is inside. (ps: if you're in the same case as I am)

Answer (score 0):

If the error is in the `.specs` file
`app/app.component.spec.ts(7,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'`.

add this to the top of your file and `npm install rxjs`

```
import { range } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: Why would installing and importing an unused function help solving typing issues? I doubt that this is really a valid answer

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your tsconfig.json, and be sure that you don't have "**/*.spec.ts"
in **exclude**

```
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
```

My working tsconfig.json
[image]