# how to configure unit test angular-cli@webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I've just upgraded my project from angular-cli beta.10 to angular-cli@webpack (beta.18) and now none of my specs.ts are resolving (cannot find name 'describe', etc). Is there any info on how to configure unit test for my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is everything how to configure properly your karma-jasmine and webpack
[Check it](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#!#test-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you follow this guide from the angular-cli's wiki...

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Upgrading-from-Beta.10-to-Beta.14

Comment: Yes I followed it

Answer (score 0):

As well as the Angular documentation, the link below fixed my issue
[angular-2-unit-tests-cannot-find-name-describe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020022/angular-2-unit-tests-cannot-find-name-describe)