# Angular6 - cannot resolve 'fs' in selenium-webdriver\lib

Tags: angular, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, angular6

I'm having an issue running "*ng test*" in my angular project.  When I run I get the following output:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   'C:\Users\test\Desktop\ui-portal\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib'
>   @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js 28:11-24  @
>   ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js  @
>   ./src/app/container/container.component.spec.ts  @ ./src .spec.ts$ 
>   @ ./src/test.ts

-

> ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/devmode.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   'C:\Users\test\Desktop\ui-portal\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib'
>   @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/devmode.js 25:11-24  @
>   ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js  @
>   ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js  @
>   ./src/app/container/container.component.spec.ts  @ ./src .spec.ts$ 
>   @ ./src/test.ts

I've been searching for an answer but can't find anything that's helping - has anyone seen this particular issue before?  My package.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "ui-portal",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.1",
    "applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.18",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.1.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "source-sans-pro": "^2.20.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/chai": "^3.5.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "diff": "^3.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.3",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-tfs-reporter": "^1.0.1",
    "mocha": "^4.0.1",
    "onchange": "^3.2.1",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers guys!  Really not making progress with this one :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by running the following commands in sequence:

> npm install --save-dev @types/jasmine
>
> npm install
>
> npm audit fix

Now running the *ng test* actually runs my unit-tests! :-D

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue with ng test on

> Angular CLI: 6.1.2 Node: 8.9.1

The problem for me was using the

> wrong `HttpClient`. import in my test file.

Make sure your HttpClient is from `'@angular/common/http';` and not imported from `Selenium`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: after solving this issue I will be more carefull about VS Code quick-fix options.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, because it imported `EventEmitter` from `'protractor'` instead of `angular-core`

Comment: I had imported from 'selenium-webdriver'. Your answer has saved me hours of debugging.

Comment: This resolved my issue, wow I feel bad for that goof!!! Well done!

Answer (score 3):

For some reasons my IntelliJ added:

```
import { beforeEach } from 'selenium-webdriver/testing';
```

which was causing the issue. Removing it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `import 'jasmine'` from the ts file.

If the editor is complaining about missing types jasmine

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      ...
    ]
 }
```

More [reference](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8357)

Comment: When I remove jasmine, I get a host of errors where it can't find the jasmine code in my unit test files, such as beforeEach and describe etc:  ERROR in src/app/app.component.spec.ts(14,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(19,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020022/angular-2-unit-tests-cannot-find-name-describe?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: This article lead to me resolving the issue!  Thanks very much! :-D  I will post exactly what I did to fix, in case it's useful for others!

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem when I allowed Visual Studio Code auto import **EvenEmitter** as shown below:

**import { EventEmitter } from 'protractor';**

I fixed it by changing the import location as shown below:

**import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';**

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: literally my answer from below...