# error TS2552: Cannot find name 'xdescribe'. Did you mean 'describe'?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-node, angular-unit-test

I am working on unit testing in angular application. And I have skipped some test suites by using `xdescrie`. Unfortunately, it is showing errors like `error TS2552: Cannot find name 'xdescribe'. Did you mean 'describe'?` when running the test by using the command `ng test`.

I have installed the package `@types/jasmine` as a Dev dependencies

Comment: Check the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020022/angular-2-unit-tests-cannot-find-name-describe

Answer (score 0):

the most probable cause for this problem could be that the package is not installed properly.

try to run this in your npm:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jasmine
```

and then on the top of your .spec.ts file

```
import 'jasmine';
```